# Splitting text file by specific string/keyword

Tags: powershell

I have a txt file like this:

```
GroupA
SERVER0953
SERVER93785
COMP3784523
SERVER92374
ENDOFSECTION
GroupB
SERVER840
COMP395
COMP38954
LAP89384
ENDOFSECTION
GroupC
COMP395023
SERVER8294034
COMP38483
COMP384784
LAP4834982
LAP95483
LAP38584
COMP394894
ENDOFSECTION
```

I want to split at ENDOFSECTION and then loop through all the elements from the previous ENDOFSECTION e.g. I want to loop through the following to add every computer from [1] to [-1] to a the group name at [0]. I want to repeat this same action for every section.

```
GroupA
SERVER0953
SERVER93785
COMP3784523
SERVER92374
```

I have this:

```
Get-Content c:\temp\test.txt | foreach-Object {$_.split("ENDOFSECTION") }
```

But it doesn't seem to work on POSH5, but does on POSH7. I need to have it work on POSH5 and how do I put this into an object/array so I can run actions against each chunk

Comment: `Get-Content` reads files _line by line_ by default, so your solution attempt cannot work in either PowerShell edition, given that you need to process _blocks_ of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

- Note: The following uses a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) to simulate input from a file. The solution relies on the input to be *single, multi-line string*. Thus, with *file* input, use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) with the 
  `-Raw` switch (e.g., `Get-Content -Raw file.txt`)

```bash
@'
GroupA
SERVER0953
SERVER93785
COMP3784523
SERVER92374
ENDOFSECTION
GroupB
SERVER840
COMP395
COMP38954
LAP89384
ENDOFSECTION
GroupC
COMP395023
SERVER8294034
COMP38483
COMP384784
LAP4834982
LAP95483
LAP38584
COMP394894
ENDOFSECTION
'@ -split '\r?\nENDOFSECTION(?:\r?\n|\z)' -ne '' | # split into blocks
  ForEach-Object { # process each block
    $group, $servers = $_ -split '\r?\n' # split block into group-name and server-name lines
    # Now you can work with the group name in $group,
    # and the list of servers in $servers, e.g.:
    [pscustomobject] @{
      Group = $group
      Servers = $servers
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
Group  Servers
-----  -------
GroupA {SERVER0953, SERVER93785, COMP3784523, SERVER92374}
GroupB {SERVER840, COMP395, COMP38954, LAP89384}
GroupC {COMP395023, SERVER8294034, COMP38483, COMP384784…}
```